# clock() Returns Negative Value?

Tags: c++, function, clock

I have created a server program, and a certain error has occurred twice where the function 'clock()' has returned a negative value (and crashed the server). Both times it occurred when the program had been running for more than 100 hours, on a Windows 32-bit VPS.

Here's the setup I have in main.cpp (cut where appropriate):

```
while (1) {
    Sleep(STEP);

            //execute main code like connection handling, AI, etc.

    //check for clock error
    if (clock() < 0) {
        //error saved here

                //close server
        return 0;
    }
}
```

That's it, pretty simple. clock() is used throughout the rest of the program extensively, so when it glitches up like this it causes a lot of problems.

I am wondering, why does it return a negative value, and how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e2ess30.aspx) it can return -1 if "the amount of elapsed time is unavailable". Unfortunately they don't explain how the time would be unavailable.

The definition of `clock_t` is `long` which is a 32-bit signed value - it can hold 2**31 before it overflows. The value of `CLOCKS_PER_SECOND` is 1000, so it should be good for 596 hours.

Comment: The program may have been running for 596 hours...to be honest I lost track of how long it's up for at once. If so that might be the issue. Could I reset clock_t to 0 somehow if clock() returns -1?

Comment: According to C99, "If
the processor time used is not available or its value **cannot be represented** , the function
returns the value (clock_t)(-1)."

Comment: @Matthew, there are lots of other clock functions available that don't have this problem - use one of those.